# Can Anyone Help Identify this Bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike

If a Schwinn is made it China, does it have any resale value?

The decals say "Schwinn Cruiser," the pedals are Schwinn, as is the badge and the pannier bike rack, BUT the Serial Number seems to be "SL16 36" (or 38) which I can't find in any database (perhaps it's not from Chicago, or was made by someone else for Schwinn - made in China, just noticed, Giant?

The Schwinn badge says "Schwinn Quality," and looks like the one from 1995, according to this page:  http://re-cycle.com/History/Schwinn/SwnC_Badges.aspx

[schwinn cruiser made in China](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsrKM.jpg)

[image: Serial]

[image: badge schwinn quality]

Many thanks for any quidance that can be offered : 0

Comment: Resale value for older generic mass-produced bikes like this is often more correlated to how the bike functions than what brand/year it is. Do the tires hold air? Are the wheels in good shape? Can you ride it safely? If yes, then it might have value. If not, then you might consider either donating it to a good cause or learning how to fix bikes.

Comment: Thank, Kris...I was just clearing out storage and thought I'd offer it for sale, but didn't want to ask too much.  I know the Schwinn name no longer carries much eclat, but did want to make sure it's a real Schwinn, since I don't see the straight down tubes on any other model.

Comment: @Lorra the photos you provided are not enough to work with. Can you make more, so the bike can be seen from different angles?

Comment: Why sell it at all?  You could give it a go and see how you like riding again.   Used bikes aren't worth a lot, and Schwinn's not exactly high end.

Comment: Realistically, a mass-produced bike that isn't seriously old isn't going to be worth anything much: something that cost, say, $100 new thirty years ago is very unlikely to be worth even that much today. You think this one's maybe from 1995. Look at it this way: if you were a collector, would you pay top-dollar for something that new? If you wanted something to ride, would you pay top-dollar for something that old?

Answer (score 1):

There's a Schwinn serial decoder at  https://bikehistory.org/serial-number.html   could be a useful tool, but need the full serial number.

Try cleaning that area with warm water and dishwash, then dry it off then use an oblique light from a torch/flashlight to help illuminate the deeper metal of the characters.